# Vuetify v-select height of each option very big 40px. I need twice less

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**I have vuetifyjs v-select**

Vuetify standart `v-select` height of each option very big 40px. If long list it contain full page.I need twice less

```
<v-select
  :items="countries"
  label="Select country"
></v-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have solution.**

Just add to styles section custom classes.

Without padding and set less min-height by !important

Minimum is 16px - `min-height: 16px !important;`

```
<style >
 .v-list-item__content{
   padding: 0 !important;
 }
 .v-list-item{
   min-height: 24px !important;
 }
</style>
```